# Discord bot reading reactions

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I need to implement some of the feature and one of the feature is implementing polls type feature. Can't use public discord bots due to some policies so we have to implement something on my own. Did some research yesterday and was able to make basic bot using **python3** and `commands` api from `discord.ext`. Now what i need to figure out is:

1. Read reactions added by a user to a message?
2. Create a message with reactions (like bots which create reaction polls?)
3. Pin a message?
4. I believe from `ctx` i can get `user` `tags` (admin etc). Is there a better way to do so?

Couldn't find anything helpful on [Commands reference page](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html) or probably i am looking at wrong documentation. any help would be appreciated.

thanks

---

**Updated**: Thanks guys. now i am stuck at how to add emoji, here is my code

```
poll_emojis = {0: ':zero:', 1: ':one:', 2: ':two:', 3: ':three:', 4: ':four:'}

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$create_poll'):

        poll_content = message.content.split('"')
        poll_text = poll_content[1]
        poll_options = []
        poll_option_text = ''
        count = 0
        for poll_option in poll_content[2:]:
            if poll_option.strip() != '':
                poll_options.append(poll_option)
                poll_option_text += '{0}: {1}\t'.format(poll_emojis[count], poll_option)
                count += 1

        posted_message = await message.channel.send('**{0}**\n{1}'.format(poll_text, poll_option_text))

        count = 0
        for poll_option in poll_options:
            await posted_message.add_reaction(Emoji(poll_emojis[count]))
            count += 1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "`user` `tags`"?

Answer (score 6):

As an aside, given you're starting this project, and are already using the rewrite documentation, make sure you're using the rewrite version. There are some questions on here about how to make sure, and how to get it if you're not, but it's better documented and easier to use. My answers below assume you are using [discord.py-rewrite](/questions/tagged/discord.py-rewrite)

1. [`Message.reactions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.reactions) is a list of [`Reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Reaction)s.  You could get a mapping of reactions to their counts with

   ```
   {react.emoji: react.count for react in message.reactions}
   ```
2. You could react to the message immediately after posting it:

   ```
   @bot.command()
   async def poll(ctx, *, text):
       message = await ctx.send(text)
       for emoji in ('', ''):
           await message.add_reaction(emoji)
   ```
3. You can use [`Message.pin`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.pin): `await message.pin()`

I'm not sure what you mean by "`user` `tags`".  Do you mean roles?

I would write your command as

```
@bot.command()
async def create_poll(ctx, text, *emojis: discord.Emoji):
    msg = await ctx.send(text)
    for emoji in emojis:
        await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Note that this will only work for custom emoji, the ones you have added to your own server (This is because `discord.py` treats unicode emoji and custom emoji differently.)  This would accept commands like

```
!create_poll "Vote in the Primary!" :obamaemoji: :hillaryemoji:
```

assuming those two emoji were on the server you send the command in.

With the new [`commands.Greedy`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#greedy) converter, I would rewrite the above command like so:

```
@bot.command()
async def create_poll(ctx, emojis: Greedy[Emoji], *, text):
    msg = await ctx.send(text)
    for emoji in emojis:
        await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
```

So invocation would be a little more natural, without the quotes:

```
!create_poll :obamaemoji: :hillaryemoji: Vote in the Primary!
```

Comment: thanks. could you tell how can i add reaction to the message? I have updated my code and when i try to add reaciton with the emoji, i get error that says `Unknown Emoji`

Comment: @EmAe Yeah, this is (in my opinion) one of the big failings of how `discord.py` represents emoji.  Custom emoji are represented by `discord.Emoji` objects, but unicode emoji are represented by their corresponding unicode character. So you end up with a weird gray area in which emoji that are indistinguishable to users in the Discord client have to be handled differently by your bot. If you want to represent a unicode emoji in your source code, use the unicode character, `'①'` or an escape sequence `'\u2460'`, instead of the shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

I have just seen what you are stuck and I was stuck at this too. The solution is that reactions are not actually things like ":one:" it is actual emojis, there are different ways to fix this, the simplest being adding them to the dictionary yourself. Or you can use `python3 -m pip install discordhelp` and use the functions for it [listed here](https://pypi.org/project/discordhelp/).

Comment: Please note since I am the creator of the `discordhelp` library, feel free to ask me about it, also please tell me if it works or not, because I am unable to get it to work on my computer.