# How to count reactions on a post with a discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Here is my code:

```
import discord
import asyncio

channel = None

async def ex(args, message, client, invoke):

    global channel
    channel = message.channel
    one = ""
    two = ""
    three = ""

    one_count = 0
    two_count = 0
    three_count = 0

    vote = discord.Embed(title="**[POLL]**", description=" ", color=0x00ff00)
    vote.add_field(name="Please vote for the match type:", value="- "+one+" Solos\n- "+two+" Duos\n- "+three+" Squads", inline=True)
    message_1 = await client.send_message(channel, embed=vote)

    await client.add_reaction(message_1, one)
    await client.add_reaction(message_1, two)
    await client.add_reaction(message_1, three)
```

Any ideas as to how I can make it count the amount of reactions after a short wait period?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord bot reading reactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737538/discord-bot-reading-reactions)

Comment: That post uses the discord rewrite, not what I’m using

Comment: `{react.emoji: react.count for react in message.reactions}` should work for both.  Then just access the emoji you're interested in from that dict.

Comment: I don't understand how to use that in context, can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `asyncio.await` to wait for the vote to close, then you can get the counts of all reactions and use that to determine the winner

```
async def ex(args, message, client, invoke):  # I don't understand these arguments, they seem unneccessary

    channel = message.channel
    choices = {"": "Solos",
               "": "Duos",
               "": "Squads"}

    vote = discord.Embed(title="**[POLL]**", description=" ", color=0x00ff00)
    value = "\n".join("- {} {}".format(*item) for item in choices.items()) 
    vote.add_field(name="Please vote for the match type:", value=value, inline=True)

    message_1 = await client.send_message(channel, embed=vote)

    for choice in choices:
        await client.add_reaction(message_1, choice)

    await aynsio.sleep(60)  # wait for one minute
    message_1 = await client.get_message(channel, message_1.id)


    counts = {react.emoji: react.count for react in message_1.reactions}
    winner = max(choices, key=counts.get)

    await client.send_message(channel, "{} is the winner".format(choices[winner]))
```

Comment: Throws back an error?

`winner = max(choices, key=counts.get)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`

Comment: @BenjaminJones It looks like the `message_1` object that we already had a reference to wasn't being updated to reflect the reactions to it.  We can get around this by re-acquiring the `Message` object through `get_message`, using the fact that we know it's id.